# ReactJS web site implementation error with multiple elements return

Tags: reactjs

I tried the below code **example 01** from [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) and its working fine, But when I tried adding multiple elements (**example 02)** to return with this component it doesn't work.

**Example 01**

```
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return e( 
        'button',
          { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
        'Like'  
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

**Example 02**

```
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return e(
        <div> 
          <a href="#" >Login</a>
          <a href="#" >Logout</a>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

**PS:** I'm a newbie to reactJS and appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: in your second example where are you changing the state of component?? i mean liked=true??

Comment: @joy just ignore that part, i just only want to learn how to render multiple html elements as return. :)

Comment: if you are about how to render multiple html elements for i.e multiple div and other block level elements with single return ?then you can use <React.Fragment> as a container component

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `createElement` with wrong syntax; here's the signature:

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

In your case, the right call would be

```
return e(
  'div',
  null,
  [
    e('a', { href: '#' }, 'Login'), 
    e('a', { href: '#' }, 'Logout')
  ]
);
```

However you could directly return HTML with no need of using `createElement`, just change the render to:

```
return (
  <div> 
    <a href="#" >Login</a>
    <a href="#" >Logout</a>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick prompt @Dario, the first case works fine as you suggested, actually, I need to ignore that complex structure and proceed with direct HTML output.

I tried your second suggestion and still, it doesn't work in my example. any idea on this?.

Comment: You probably need to change `ReactDOM.render` command to `ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, domContainer);`... Check here https://codesandbox.io/s/vylv4k8ok0

Comment: That works nicely and thanks for the example @Dario. 

But got a question on including react-dom in that way. With this example (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyKaWG) I'm trying to add it as a hosted script in the HTML file.